How to write file to external Android storage from Nativescript
I want to export file to /sdcard/Documents/ or /storage/emulated/0/Documents/
I have needed permission on application declaration
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

I try to use File class from Nativescript
const extFolder: Folder = knownFolders.externalDocuments()
const extOutPath = path.join(extFolder.path, '123.json');
const extOutfile = File.fromPath(extOutPath);


but last line (256 on screen) always produced error
ERROR Error: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted

I try to write my own function, based on native android Java function, something like that (I don't sure that is correct function, I'm not Java Guru), but in Nativescript we have access to android.os.Environment and java.io.FileInputStream
  exportFileToExternalStorage(fullInputFilePath, targetPath, fileName) {
   request(targetPath + fileName).then((response) => {

  console.log(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)

  try {
  var myInput = new java.io.FileInputStream(
    fullInputFilePath
  );

  var myOutput = new java.io.FileOutputStream(targetPath + fileName);

    var buffer = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
      java.lang.Byte.class.getField("TYPE").get(null),
      1024
    );
    var length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

  } catch (err) {
    console.info("Error", err);
    alert(err.message)
  }

  //Close the streams
  myOutput.flush();
  myOutput.close();
  myInput.close();
})
}

but faced with the same error in attempt to write to /sdcard/Documents/ or /storage/emulated/0/Documents/
Key android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" also not working.
What going wrong? How to overcome this restriction?

I use advice https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/10285
and this issue solved. Android transformed  'content://media/external/downloads/33' to /storage/emulated/0/Download/Nativescript

But... unfortunately, this is not clear solution, debug version working fine, but if you will try to create Release version, you will faced with error

This error message usually means that you need manually define something additional modules in Gradle script, I found 6 differences between release and debug versions, 6 additional modules automatically included to debug version:
META-INF/androidx.cardview_cardview.version
META-INF/androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version
META-INF/androidx.documentfile_documentfile.version
META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version
META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version
META-INF/androidx.print_print.version

